# How to modify compressed/encoded content in HTTP response captured from Proxy socket/buffer, before forwarding to client

Tags: python, http, encoding, proxy, gzip

We want capture & modify the HTTP response inside proxy just before sending it back to client. We are using python-proxy (http://code.google.com/p/python-proxy/). When we read the HTTP stream from the proxy socket/buffer, the HTTP content/body is encoded/compressed. We need to decompress/decode the HTTP content/body, modify the content and compress/encode it back & return it to proxy to forward the modified response back to client. How do we achieve this using python? Any help will be appreciated.

NOTE: We cannot make any direct call on the URLs since this code will be running inside Proxy.

Comment: Aaaand what have you tried thus far? :)

Comment: We tried the following thus far: write the HTTP content to a file, read the compressed HTTP body/content and pass the content to decompress function, but it fails to decompress the data. My guess we are missing the extraction of correct start/end of the binary to decompress.

Comment: A good idea is to post that relevant code that fails :) Trying to look up how to modify data from within another library (python-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

```
import gzip
from io import BytesIO

def compress(data):
    if type(data) != type(b'bytes'):
        data = bytes(data, 'UTF-8')
    return gzip.compress(data)

def decompress(data):
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=BytesIO(data)) as fh:
        try:
            unzipped = fh.read()
        except struct.error:
            return None
    return unzipped
```

Assuming a few things:

1. The Content-Encoding is gzip
2. You can actually retrieve the data from the proxy library
3. You've gathered the data in a correct manner if chunked etc so that it can be decompressed.

Comment: Thanks Torxed for your prompt response. The challenge we are facing is, how do we extract the HTTP body or compressed part of the HTTP content (start/end of compress byte) removing the header and then pass that content to the decompress function.

Comment: Yes, content-encoding is gzip. we dont see any lib in the Python proxy (which we are using here) to extract the data decompressed. We read raw http response data from the buffer/socket. On 3rd point, yes we also see content-length mentioned as "chunked" as well. not sure how do we handle this

Comment: @user1109998 if you've managed to do `write the HTTP content to a file` then it should be a matter of `headers, data = data.split('\r\n\r\n'); decompress(data)`, as simple as that.

Comment: Got your point, great! I will give it a try now and post my response. Sorry for being amataure

Comment: @user1109998 Heh, don't be sorry :) It's a valid question!